# Flexible Triangular Box with patterns for divs above and below

Tags: html, css

I need some help - if you look at this jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/w9LNN/26/) you can see what I need done.

```
<div class="email-millions clearfix">
<h1>E-MAIL MILLIONS</h1>
<div class="top-border">
<div class="top-border-left"></div>
<div class="top-border-right"></div>
</div></div>

<div class="kindle-empire clearfix">
<h1 class="museo-300 text-center">div 2</h1>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.email-millions { background: #352f42 url('http://www.insiderinternetsuccess.com/wp-content/themes/iis/img/dark_blue_paper_BG.jpg');color: #fff;}
.kindle-empire { background: url('http://www.insiderinternetsuccess.com/wp-content/themes/iis/img/paper_BG-tile.jpg'); }
.top-border { width: 100%; position: relative; left: 0; }
.top-border-left { border-top-width: 30px; border-right-width: 0; border-bottom-width: 0; border-left-width: 800px; border-color: transparent transparent transparent #ffffff; float: left; }
.top-border-left { border-style: solid solid inset solid; width: 0; height: 0; }
.top-border-right { border-top-width: 0; border-right-width: 0; border-bottom-width: 30px; border-left-width: 800px; border-color: transparent transparent #ffffff transparent; float: right; }
.top-border-right { border-style: inset solid solid solid; width: 0; height: 0; }

.clearfix:before,.clearfix:after {    content: " "; /* 1 */    display: table; /* 2 */ }
.clearfix:after { clear: both; }
.clearfix { *zoom: 1; }
```

There is a triangle at the bottom of the first div that uses the same background as the div it is within (in my case a purple pattern).

However, the second div also has an image and because of the way the triangle has been made there is a white background between the 2 divs.

Is there a way, without using images, to create it so there is no white space between the 2 divs containing a patterned image?

Answer (score 0):

I would put your pattern in a div that surrounds all your other divs and use a png for your triangle instead. PNG's can be made to have transparent areas

Comment: would the triangle png be responsive and stretch when the browser width increases?